# C: vsprintf overwriting an array

Tags: c, overwrite, printf

I'm having a problem when using the function vsprintf.

I have 3 functions to open, close and write to a XML file. The open function stores the first word of the input text in an array, and the close function closes the tag with that word. The problem is that the array where I store the close tag to use gets overwritten in each call to the open or the write functions (even when the write function hasn't any reference to the array used to store the close tag).

```
int xml_level = 0;
char *xml_header[64];
FILE *xml_out;

void xmlopen(const char *format, ...){
   char buffer[256];
   va_list arglist;
   va_start(arglist,format);
   vsprintf(buffer,format,arglist);
   va_end(arglist);
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<xml_level; i++){
      fprintf(xml_out,"\t");  
   }
   fprintf(xml_out,"<%s>\n",buffer);
   xml_header[xml_level] = strtok (buffer, " ");
   xml_level++;
}

void xmlclose(){
   xml_level--;
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<xml_level; i++){
      fprintf(xml_out,"\t");  
   }
   fprintf(xml_out,"</%s>\n",xml_header[xml_level]);
}

void xmlwrite(const char *format, ...){
   char buffer[256];
   va_list arglist;
   va_start(arglist,format);
   vsprintf(buffer,format,arglist);
   va_end(arglist);
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<xml_level; i++){
      fprintf(xml_out,"\t");  
   }
   fprintf(xml_out,"<%s/>\n",buffer);
}
```

Example of use:

```
xmlopen("Hello Word");
xmlopen("Foo Bar");
xmlwrite("Potato");
xmlwrite("Sentence longer than the other ones");
xmlclose();
xmlclose();
```

Example of output:

```
<Hello Word>
        <Foo Bar>
                <Potato/>
                <Sentence longer than the other ones/>
        </Sentence longer than the>
</Sentence longer than the>
```

Where it should be:

```
<Hello Word>
        <Foo Bar>
                <Potato/>
            <Sentence longer than the other ones/>
        </Foo>
</Hello>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Change this line:

```
xml_header[xml_level] = strtok (buffer, " ");
```

to

```
xml_header[xml_level] = strdup (strtok(buffer, " "));
```

And remember to free xml_headers when your program exit.

**[UPDATE]**
Of course, you also need to check possible corner cases such as `strtok` returns `NULL`, etc...

**Explanation**

`strtok` won't allocate extra storage for the returned tokens. My personal suspect is that it will subsititute the delimiters with `\0` **in place** and return you the pointer to the start of next token every time.

Note that in your code, you allocate 256 bytes of buffer both in `xmlopen` and `xmlwrite` at the beginning, and recall that this buffer will be allocated in stack. So in your calls to `xmlopen` or `xmlwrite`, `buffer` will actually point to the same address (you can print its value to verify this `printf("buffer is %p\n", buffer)`, it's `0xbff2481c` on my machine).

First, you call `xmlopen("Hello World")`, and `xml_header[0]` will point to `"Hello"`, which is also the start of `buffer`. Then you call `xmlopen("Foo Bar")`, and `xml_header[1]` will point to `"Foo"`, which also the start of `buffer`. Then you call `xmlwrite("Portato")` and `xmlwrite("Sentence longer than the other ones")`. Note that at this point, `xml_header[1]` still point to the start of `buffer`, which now is `"Sentence longer than the other ones"`. So when you call `xmlclose()`, it will print out that sentence instead of your expected token, which is overwrite by your later buffer.

Interestingly, if you allocate different buffer size in `xmlopen` and `xmlwrite`, say 256 bytes for `xmlopen` and 128 bytes for `xmlwrite`, then you will see that `xmlclose` will print out some mess codes which is not readable.

You can verify all these by inspect (e.g., print) the values of `xml_header[0], xml_header[1]` and `buffer`.

Comment: Note that strdup will fail if strtok returns NULL.

Comment: @PaulR: Thanks for your reminder! Error checking is absolutely needed. I just omit them here for emphasizing on the problem itself. I've updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you only have one local variable called `buffer` in `xmlopen` and you're (a) storing pointers to it for use outside the function (undefined behaviour) and (b) trying to use it across multiple calls (logic bug).

You need to *allocate storage* for the strings returned by `strtok`, and make sure you dispose of them later, e.g. change:

```
xml_header[xml_level] = strtok (buffer, " ");
```

to:

```
char * s = strtok(buffer, " ");
if (s != NULL)
{
    xml_header[xml_level] = strdup(s);
}
```

(Disposing of the these strings later when they are no longer needed is left as an exercise for the reader.)